# Javascript variable value in a callback are getting reset in closure

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5, asynccallback

I am experiencing a very strange behavior in some part of a ES5 JavaScript module that I am trying to refactor.

As I know in JavaScript, when an async callback uses a variable present into parent function scope(The scope in which the callback was defined), the value of the variable becomes the latest value of the variable at that timestamp when the callback is being executed. But in the following piece of code, somehow the variable `pageNum` value is set to `0` every time it is run. In the code, it is trying to capture pages one by one from hard disk. When the page gets uploaded, it's index is showed to notify which page is uploaded.

Please have a look at the following code:

```
this.nextPageIndex = 1;
function capturePage(pageNum) {
  //Lots of things being done....
  function statusUpdate() {
    console.log(pageNum + "is being uploaded...");
  }
  captureSinglePage(statusUpdate);
}

function captureSinglePage(statuscallBack) {
  if (capture job running) { // when async job is running call statuscallBack() to send status of page capture
    statuscallBack();
  } else if (page capture job done) { // when async job is done
    singlePageCaptured();
  }
}

function singlePageCaptured() {
  //check if all pages are captured, if not
  capturePage(this.nextPageIndex++);
}
```

Now `capturePage` is being called on the 0th element of an array of pages.
It is printing `"0 is being uploaded"` even when next pages are uploaded. 
Shouldn't it print the correct pageIndexes?

Please let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: We don't know what the value of `nextPageIndex` is. Not enough info here. But yes, `statusUpdate` will close over the `pageNum` parameter, and use its current value, which doesn't get changed according to your code.

Comment: sorry for the incident. Edited the question for better understanding and proper value of  `nextPageIndex`.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, there's still no indication of where the issue would be, except that if `pageNum` is always `0`, then the call to `capturePage()` must always be passing `0`. Only way that would change is if something *inside* the `capturePage()` function is changing its value, but that doesn't happen in your example.

Comment: I have set a debug point inside the body of `capturePage()` and one inside the `statusUpdate`. The thing is when `capturePage` is being executed `pageNum` gets proper value, just after that when the `statuscallback` get executed, the value gets overwritten to 0. I have really no idea how the value gets changed though the clossure scope has diffeent value.

Comment: Need an actual demonstration of the issue. You'll need to update the code in your question. Your `//Lots of things being done....` could be changing it.